# How can I implement split for newlines that come from a browser textarea?

Tags: c#

I have a browser text box that my users type into. I am trying the following to split up the contents that they enter by new line. I tried the following but none work. I either get errors or no splitting:

```
content.Split("\n", StringSplitOptions.None) < gives me an error Error The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments    

content.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.None) < gives an error: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

content.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None) < doesn't split as needed. When I look at the source in debugger I just see \n characters. 

content.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None) < doesn't split as needed. When I look at the source in debugger I just see \n characters.
```

Can anyone suggest what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `content.Split` correctly:

```
content.Split(new [] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
content.Split(new [] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The third option does not work as in a Windows environment `Environment.NewLine` is "\n\r", but your sting contains only "\n".

In the fourth option you look for "\n\r" again.

Alternatively you could use

```
content.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This would split on "\r" and "\n" and remove all empty lines.

Comment: There's also `content.Split("\n".ToCharArray(), StringSPlitOptions.None)`